# BLDC working driver

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am trying to drive a BLDC motor. I was driving 2 phases and keeping the 3rd phase floating so as to measure the BEMF in it. But, what I find is whatever voltage is applied on the +ve or high side comes as it is (in voltage) on the float phase. Am I looking at this wrong or is the motor behaving weird?

Comment: so effectively, my ADC sees a behaviour that mimics the duty cycle provided in the high side of the Motor driver and not  the expected BEMF.

Comment: Is that an answer or an addendum to the question?

Comment: sir, its an addendum. new to this forum. sorry

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! You really need to tell us the details of the motor and your drive circuit before we can provide any meaningful answers.

Comment: i have a 3 phase bldc (from hobby king). i am using mosfets and transistors to drive the motor phases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the motor is behaving perfectly normally. If you want to measure back EMF in this manner, you can only do it during those periods in which no excitation is being applied to the motor.

Given this restriction, you can actually measure the back EMF on any of the windings.

Comment: thank u sir. The thing is I have just 1 PWM (most of the docs have multi PWM per state) per state.Its centre oriented. Lets say I make AH on and BLow on. The C is float. Now, whatever is given on AH (PWM) is received on C phase as well. SO , I am unable to measure '0' crossing.
Am I doing something foolish :)

Comment: So what u r suggesting is measure the BEMF during the off time of the PWM. right.